# How to properly bind the SelectedIndex of a TabControl?

Tags: c#, wpf

Can I have a tab control in a Wpf window bound to a property of the Window, e.g.:

```
    <TabControl Grid.Row="0" SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedTabIndex, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <TabItem Header="Tab1"/>
        <TabItem Header="Tab2"/>
    </TabControl>
```

Property on Window:

```
 public int SelectedTabIndex { get; set; }
```

Such that, when the tab is changed by the user, the Window property is automatically set to the new index?  I tried this out, but it doesn't appear to be doing anything with the `SelectedTabIndex` when I set a breakpoint on the `set`.  Is there something I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the property raises PropertyChanged in your setter and the VM class (or Window in this case) support INotifyPropertyChanged.

If it's still not hitting your setter, then ensure your output window in Visual Studio is set to Binding Errors and check that to ensure that it's not throwing errors trying to bind for some reason (which would typically indicate your DataContext isn't set correctly, either for the Window as a whole or by the time you reach your Tabcontrol due to being changed further up the XAML with binding)

Comment: I had to do something like this... does this make sense? `SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedTabIndex, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}, Mode=TwoWay}"`